# $\sum_{n\mathop=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n}}{9^n(2n)!}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble with finding the sum of the following series:

$$\sum_{n\mathop=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n}}{9^n(2n)!}$$

Usually I would try to differentiate, but here its really inconvenient due to the factorial, which I'm not even sure it's going to help in any way. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use proper spelling and punctuation?

Comment: It is $\cos\pi/3=1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Taylor series of cosine:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{n\mathop=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n}}{9^n(2n)!}
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n\mathop=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n \left(\frac\pi3\right)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
&=& \displaystyle \cos \left( \dfrac \pi 3 \right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac12 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: thanks, so i was basically supposed to recognise it was cos x with some alterations?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: thanks for editing my post, im still trying to figure out how to code my notations so its easier to read.

Comment: @dvd280 I can forgive you if you don't mathjax, but can you not say "Usually **i** would try to differentiate, but here **its** really **inconvinient** due to the factorial, which **im** not even sure its going to help in any way.any ideas?"?

Comment: @KennyLau When I thought this was an english site rather than Maths site. Hahahah.

Answer (score 4):

We need $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(i\pi/3)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Now as $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!},$

$$2S=e^{i\pi/3}+e^{-i\pi/3}=2\cos\dfrac\pi3$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n}\pi^{2n} \over 9^{n}\pars{2n}!} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\ic^{2n}\pi^{2n} \over 3^{2n}\pars{2n}!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\ic^{n}\pi^{n} \over 3^{n}\,n!}\,
{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2} =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\pi\ic/3}^{n} \over n!} +
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\pi\ic/3}^{n} \over n!}}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\pi\ic/3}^{n} \over n!} =
\Re\exp\pars{{\pi \over 3}\,\ic} = \cos\pars{\pi \over 3} = \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}