# question about the cosh function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having a hard time finding the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^n}{(2n)!}$$

I know it has something to do with cosine since it also has $(2n)!$ in the denominator and it might also be connected with $e^x$ since the terms look very similar.
I have tried playing with algebraic manipulations but again it did not help.
Any help with starting would be appreciated

Comment: do you mean $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{(2n)!}$$?

Comment: the explicit form of you finite sum containes the hypergeomtric function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cosh(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5^k}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt5^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \cosh(\sqrt5) = \frac{e^\sqrt5+e^{-\sqrt5}}{2}$$

EDIT- Let 
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
Then $f$ is even, $g$ is odd, and $f(x)+g(x)=e^x$. Note that $f$ and $g$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$e^x+e^{-x} = (f(x)+g(x))+(f(x)-g(x)) = 2f(x)$$
Therefore,
$$f(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$

Comment: are you sure that (2n)!=2*n! ?

Comment: @dvd280 That's just a simple typo on his end

Comment: but why is it devided by 2?

Comment: $\cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$

Comment: thing is that we have never seen the cosh function, so we are supposed to find it- not use it- ie show that the taylor sum is equal to  the function you wrote.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my post to include some reasoning as for how you could come about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

$$e^{-y}+e^y=?$$

Can you recognize $y$ here?

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265299/sum-n-mathop-0-infty-frac-1n-pi2n9n2n/2265304#2265304

Comment: i have never seen the cosh function before, in this problem im asked to show that this taylor sum is equal to what you wrote, i cant use the e^-y etc equation since that is what im supposed to show.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{5^{n} \over \pars{2n}!} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\root{5}}^{2n} \over \pars{2n}!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\root{5}}^{n} \over n!}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2} \\[5mm] & =
{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{\root{5}}^{n}/n! +
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\root{5}}^{n}/n!\over 2} =
{\expo{\root{5}} + \expo{-\root{5}} \over 2} =
\bbx{\cosh\pars{\root{5}}}
\end{align}